# Kotlin regex not working for polish char ("ł") which I get at runtime

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

I've declared a regex like this:
`"(^\\d{1,}\\,\\d{2}|^0) zł$"`

Unfortunately it doesn't match below value (but it should)

`508,00 zł`

NOTE1: I've discovered, that the problem is probably with the `ł` character

NOTE2: The problem is, that i am getting this String from an API and check it at runtime (it has exact value as I described)

NOTE3: I've also tried to manually match my pattern in the debugger evaluation (when I just typed the "508, 00zł" by hand) and it matched. Unfortunately the string itself that I get doesn't match at runtime. What can be the possible problem?

Code:

```
val value = getFromApi() // 508,00 zł
val regex = "(^\\d{1,}\\,\\d{2}|^0) zł$".toRegex()
regex.matches(value) // returns false
```

Comment: Try `"""^(\d+,\d{2}|0)\szł$""".toRegex()`

Comment: Could you also use unicode for "ł" - "\u0142"?

Comment: @Sebastians The `ł` is not the problem here, I am quite sure of it because it is a single code unit, it is never defined with a "multibyte char". I suspect the problem is with the *whitespace*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you can post the answer

Comment: I posted an answer with explanations and two solutions

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you also advice me to prevent from "0,00 zł" but allow only 0 zł?

Comment: @K.Os Try `^(?!0,00)\d+(?:,\d{2})?\p{Z}*zł$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/imcJUm/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks! I think this may be the last question: how can i check for non breaking space? I've tried this but not working: (^(?!0,00)\d+,\d{2}|^0)\u00A0zł$

Comment: @K.Os `\p{Z}` matches non-breaking spaces. `\xA0` has [worked for me, too](https://ideone.com/SSjl8v).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The letter `ł` is not a culprit here since there is one Unicode representation for it.

The most common issue is the *whitespace*: it can be any Unicode whitespace there and from the looks of it, you will never be able to tell.

*To match any ASCII whitespace*, you may use **`\s`**. Here, you had this kind of whitespace, so  my top comment below the question worked for you.

*To match any Unicode whitespace*, you may use **`\p{Z}`** to match any one whitespace character, or `\p{Z}*` to match 0 or more of their occurrences:

```
val value = "508,00 zł"
val regex = """^(\d+,\d{2}|0)\p{Z}zł$""".toRegex()
// val regex = """^(\d+,\d{2}|0)\p{Z}*zł$""".toRegex()
println(regex.matches(value)) // => True
```

See [Kotlin demo](https://ideone.com/KzC9fE)

Also, note the use of the raw string literals (delimited with triple double quotation marks), they enable the use of a single backslash as the regex escape char.

Note `{1,}` is the same as `+` quantifier that matches 1 or more repetitions.